# Changing field's data of a plugin using php (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use two different stripe accounts for two different type of products. Is is possible to change field data using example below?

```
if ( has_term( 'primary_products', 'product_cat' ) ) {

$test_publishable_key = 'primary_stripe_account_key';
$test_secret_key = 'primary_stripe_account_key';

$live_publishable_key = 'primary_stripe_account_key';
$live_secret_key = 'primary_stripe_account_key';

} elseif ( has_term( 'secondary_products', 'product_cat' ) ) {

$test_publishable_key = 'secondary_stripe_account_key';
$test_secret_key = 'secondary_stripe_account_key';

$live_publishable_key = 'secondary_stripe_account_key';
$live_secret_key = 'secondary_stripe_account_key';

}
```

[image]

---

I am not looking to do anything sophisticated, since it will be a one page checkout, and you can only get one production per transaction, so I don't need to worry about having multiple type of products in the cart.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, the WooCommerce Stripe gateway plugin does not allow you to conditionally changed the secret/key pair it uses.  There are no filters or actions available in the plugin to achieve this, the only way around it would be to fork your own version of the plugin and make some modifications to the core code.